# In a package, is there a way to directly access modules, not via the package name?

Tags: python, module, package

Consider a directory `mypackage` containing the files `__init__.py`, `module_a.py` and `module_b.py`.

If `module_a` wants to access `module_b`, it has to do `import mypackage.module_b` or `import module_b from mypackage`. Simply `import module_b` fails.

Firstly: why?

Secondly: is this a problem?

Thirdly: if it is, what's the best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 3 uses *absolute imports*; any unqualified name is seen as a top-level module or package.

If you want to import from within a package, use `.` relative package prefixes; `.` is the current package, `..` the parent, etc.

So from within your `mypackage` package you can access other modules with:

```
from . import module_b
```

See the [*Intra-package References* section of the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) and the [`import` statement reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement).

Comment: So should I just always use `from .` when importing other scripts?

Comment: @AvivCohn: when importing *within a package*, using `from . import other_module` is helpful.